# pgfplotstabe, columns type

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have to import a csv data with first two string columns and other 5 numeric columns. The numeric columns names are year (ex. 2011 2012 etc.)
I want to declare strings columns and numeric column by number of column.
In the code I can't use the name of the numeric columns because it change every year. for example I want to say:
the first two columns are string columns
other columns are numeric columns.

Thank a lot

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please, be so kind and show us, what you try so far.

Comment: You can refer to columns via `display columns/[index]0/.style=string type`

Comment: @percusse `display columns/0/.style={string type}`, without the `[index]`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. OK, coffee time. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `display columns/<index>/.style={string type}`, or `every col no <index>/.style={string type}`, where `<index>` is the column number, with counting starting from zero.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread[header=has colnames]{
2011 2012 2013 2014
foo bar 11 2
bar baz 3 43
}\datatable
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  display columns/0/.style={string type},
  every col no 1/.style={string type},
]{\datatable}
\end{document}
```